# In Google Sheets - New Row should inherit LOOKUP formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have setup a lookup formula in my Google sheets to pick up values for a particular cell ( Say B1). For example, if you select 'cookies' from Dropdown in A1, it will give $10 using LOOKUP.

This part is working fine.

When I add a new row ( usually at the top ) - I want the formulae of LOOKUP to be carried over to the top most cell. This is not happening whereas other formatting/validations are getting copied to the top most row. How can I do that?

Comment: Insert within the range, rather than above / below it. If you want a better / actual answer that isn't pure speculation, you need to ask a better question. Why haven't you included any examples?

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly understand your question, but if you want vlookup work every time you enter new row, solution below will do the work Only one condition: you may put new row everywhere below row 1. Only B1 contains formula. For clarification data for vlookap are in columns C:D. In normal situation you should move them to different sheet.

```
={"price";ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP(A2:A,$D$1:$E,2,0),))}
```

**Picture:**

[image]

**Link**

[Link to working sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G4ql9ysNzcyLMCxnarj2AxQZmC-I4_wMdb3oPenEyvM/edit#gid=0)

**

Is that what you need?